# Async/Await inside Reduce

Tags: javascript, async-await, reduce

I am trying to use `async` / `await` with the `reduce` method. But somehow only the first iteration of the loop works. The papers object skips the `await` once the first `reduce` iteration is done. Is it possible to create an object using `reduce` while gathering it's content from a promise while also await for the entire process?

**Reduce function:**

```
const papers = await page.concepts.reduce(async (acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.paperID] = await getPageData(`papers/${ cur.paperID }`, 'md')
  return acc
}, {})
```

Note: `getPageData` returns a promise.

Comment: `Array.reduce` only deals with synchronous callbacks. It does not wait in each iteration regardless of whether you return a promise. Use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Bluebird has `Promise.reduce` that does exactly what you want. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reduce.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of promises and then use `Promise.all` to resolve them. If any request fails `Promise.all` will stop processing the remaining requests.

```
const papersPromises = page.concepts.map(cur => 
    getPageData(`papers/${ cur.paperID }`, 'md')
)

const result = await Promise.all(papersPromises)
// result will be an array with the results
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to fold array into an object, but, naturally, it will not handle async functions and reduce itself. Also, reduce doesn't return a Promise to await for

You can solve your case with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```
// map concepts to promises which will resolve to page data for each concept
// and await for them all at once (will run in parallel)
const pageResponses = await Promise.all(page.concepts.map(concept => getPageData(`papers/${concept.paperID}`, 'md')))
// construct object where keys are concept.paperIDs and values are pageDatas
const papers = Object.fromEntries(
  page.concepts
    .map((concept, i) => ([concept.paperID, pageResponses[i]]))
)
```

if your runtime doesn't support Object.fromEntries (and you are not using polyfill), you can do the last part like this

```
const papers = page.concepts.reduce((acc, concept, index) => acc[concept.paperID] = pageResponses[index], {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the async function returns a promise, so you would have to expect your accumulator is a promise. So you would do something like this:

```
console.log("Program starting at", Date());

function delayedResolver(a, ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("resolving at", Date());
            resolve(a);
        }, ms);
    });
}

arr = [1, 3, 5];

r = arr.reduce(async function(a, b) { 
      return await delayedResolver(a, 3000).then(v => v + b); 
    }, Promise.resolve(0));

console.log(r);

r.then(v => console.log("final value", v, "at", Date()));
```

You have to treat the accumulator as a promise, and return a new promise each time.

Note that the async function returns a promise and the `reduce` immediately applies the async function to the next pair of `(accumulator, entry)`, so all these promises returned by the async function are created almost instantly, so that's why the promises resolve all after 3 seconds, not one by one.